# Logistic Regression, SVM or NN?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, svm, neural-networks

Just attended Andrew Ng’s online course on ML and although I’ve understood the methods I seem to be missing the intuition on where to apply them in terms of classification problems.

What are the pros and cons of each method and in which situation should I chose one over the others?

From the course I got the impression that NN is a more complex algorithm and therefore capable of identification more complex, no linear, patterns but might be computationally expensive to train.

What is the advantage of SVM over LR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVM's advantages over ANN: "A significant advantage of SVMs is that whilst ANNs can suffer from multiple local minima, the solution to an SVM is global and unique. Two more advantages of SVMs are that that have a simple geometric interpretation and give a sparse solution. Unlike ANNs, the computational complexity of SVMs does not depend on the dimensionality of the input space. ANNs use empirical risk minimization, whilst SVMs use structural risk minimization. The reason that SVMs often outperform ANNs in practice is that they deal with the biggest problem with ANNs, SVMs are less prone to overfitting." for more, please look at http://www.svms.org/anns.html

I have not got much information about LR. However, as far as I know, it is the mostly used and well-known and one of the easiest methods. Linear SVM and LR are classification methods with linear decision boundaries, but they're motivated completely differently. Applications in articles show that SVM gives significant results and shows better performances.

Comment: I'd point out that linear SVM and LR tend to perform comparably in practice. The benefit of SVM is that the kernel trick allows you to easily map your features to a higher dimensional space. E.g., polynomial kernels generate interaction terms for you at essentially zero _extra_ computational cost. Compared to LR, though, SVM scales very poorly with large data sets. It is O(N^2) or O(N^3), with N being number of rows, depending on the kernel. A LR model, on the other hand, is solved iteratively with each iteration being O(N). Usually ~ 100 iterations are sufficient.